# New line in footnote elsearticle

Tags: footnotes, elsarticle

The title of the journal is too long for the footnote box, so I want it to continue on a new line but it continues beyond the text-width instead (black box in the figure). \newline and \ don't seem to work when added in the .cls file.

Anyone know how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to construct a vertical box yourself. Here is the TeX way, with manual line breaking:

```tex
\vbox{%
  \hbox{Preprint submitted to International Journal of Applied}%
  \hbox{Earth Observation and Geominformation}%
}
```

Here is one LaTeX way, with manual line breaking:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l}
  Preprint submitted to International Journal of Applied \\
  Earth Observation and Geominformation
\end{tabular}
```

Alternatively, you could make a box with a specified width and let LaTeX do the line breaking for you:

```latex
\parbox{5in}{\raggedright
  Preprint submitted to International Journal of Applied
  Earth Observation and Geominformation
}
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion and works perfectly, thanks a lot!